# Relational data not loading even LazyLoading set false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a List of Main category and Sub Category. But in debug i can see its loading only first level Main category but not loading sub category which is relational database. I have attached .edmx picture to make you sure that relational database is configured properly. LazyLoading false also not works! Any idea?

[image: pic2]

[image: pic]

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult _GuestNav()
        {
            using (var db = new TestWebDbEntities())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var Cat = db.Categories.ToList();




                return PartialView("_GuestNav", Cat);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading *prevents* child entities from being loaded, you need to explicitly tell Entity Framework what you want it to do. For this you use the `Include` method:

```
var Cat = db.Categories
    .Include(c => c.SubCategories)
    .Include(c => c.Products)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You're missing an import, try this: `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of the file.